# php preg_split into array

Tags: php, regex, split

I have the following code:

```
$input = '2018-10-28T08:36:31.521Z';
$dateTime = preg_split('[T.]', $input);
echo ($dateTime[1]);
```

The output is:

> 08:36:31.521Z

the split with 'T' works, but dosen't work with '.' (The point)

I tried:

```
'[T\.]'
```

it dosen't work also (it dosen't ever split it).

Comment: What does the expected output array look like ?

Comment: Why are you using regular expressions to manipulate a date? What are you *actually* trying to do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert one date format into another in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/convert-one-date-format-into-another-in-php)

Comment: I expect to get: the date, then time, i dont need '.521Z', i wish getting ['', '', ''] ,then i continue using the first and the secon columuns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) function, the pattern must be surrounded by slash (or other character that fits the needs). For exemple :

```
 $input = '2018-10-28T08:36:31.521Z';
 $dateTime = preg_split('/[T.]/', $input);

 echo ($dateTime[1]);
```

Output :

> 08:36:31

But for datetime manupulation, you'd better use PHP [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/fr/class.datetime.php) object.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Regular expression should start and finish with particular characters. 
My advice is always develop with settings display_errors = 1 and error_reporting(E_ALL);

```
$input = '2018-10-28T08:36:31.521Z';
$dateTime = preg_split('/[T.]/', $input);
echo ($dateTime[1]);
```

your code should work, you just missed / in regular expression